# ERC721 Contract: Adding Royalty Functionality?

Tags: erc-721, royalties

I have added the following lines in my Remix ERC721 code (from [Contracts Wizard](https://wizard.openzeppelin.com/))

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Royalty.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts@4.5.0/interfaces/IERC2981.sol";
```

What function code do I need to use to set royalty price and royalty address?

Is it as simple as adding the following to contractURI metadata?

```
"seller_fee_basis_points": 100
fee_recipient": "0x ADDRESS GOES HERE"
```

I have done an extensive search of the forums and nothing has addressed this already, so hoping this thread will shed some light.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for openSea you only need to add these fields to the contract-level metadata

```
"seller_fee_basis_points": 100
fee_recipient": "0x ADDRESS GOES HERE"
```

However I suggest to also implement the royalty standard EIP-2981

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981

you can implement both the contract level metadata and the EIP royalty standard in the same contract safely :) I do it to support OpenSea and to support newer marketplaces that adopt the standard